# Pass query arguments to report

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365, ms-office

I have a report in MS Access that takes information from a query.

In the query there is time selection so that it displays information between a time interval set by the user.

The criteria I used to create this is:

```sql
Between [Enter start date:] And [Enter end date:]
```

I want the start date and end date to be displayed in my report as soon as the user inputs it.

I tried creating 2 text boxes and using the same code but what I end up with is the same input box twice when in reality I just want the input to be done only once.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could help us help you by showing the code that creates the boxes and also how and from where you are calling that code.

Comment: Don't use dynamic popup input parameters. Reference a textbox on form for user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- On your form, create two unbound textboxes:
  Name the first textbox `StartDate` and the second textbox `EndDate`.
- Set the **Format** property for both textboxes to **General Date** to ensure that the user may only enter datetime data and is presented with a date picker.
- In the selection criteria for your query, replace the following:

  `[Enter start date:]` with `Forms![Your Form Name]![StartDate]`

  `[Enter end date:]`     with `Forms![Your Form Name]![EndDate]`

  Change `Your Form Name` to the name of your form.
- If you wish to also display the entered dates on your report, create one or two textboxes on the report whose **Control Source** is set to:

  ```
  =Forms![Your Form Name]![StartDate]
  ```

  Similarly for the End Date.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, this was exactly what I needed